# How can I make a clickable image in Bulma change the pointer on mouseOver like <button does>?

Tags: bulma

Loving the Bulma flow. 
Just wanted to make my images more obvious that they can do things when clicked.

I can bind a style with vue.js such as

```js
<figure class="image is-128x128">
<img v-bind:src="currentTrack.coverURL"   
@mouseover="hover = true" 
@mouseleave="hover = false"
@click="playAudio()" 
:style="hover ? {opacity:0.5} : {opacity:1}" alt=""/>
</figure>
```

but the mouse pointer doesn't change to something that might help it seem more button like... wondering if there is an easy Bulma attribute I can add

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### For Bulma v0.9.1 and newer

As noted by @Relisora, the class `is-clickable` now [ships natively](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/pull/3085) with Bulma, so no extra CSS is required.

---

#### Older versions

Bulma doesn't have a built-in class for that currently, unfortunately.

You can, however, easily create a class for that! To follow Bulma conventions, let's call it `is-clickable`, and define it using CSS:

```
.is-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now just include the class in the `<figure>`-element.

You can read more about the `cursor`-rule on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

Comment: Is it also possible to make it hoverable with some text appearing?

Answer (score 2):

## Bulma >= 0.9.1

Use the Bulma class `is-clickable`.

[reference](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/other-helpers/) -
[commit](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/commit/5e4bf5ed5584e532179bbd236d65451d45ffd9f4)

## Bulma < 0.9.1

You will have to add the CSS yourself, here is the code bulma used :

```
.is-clickable {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```